# Node mysql query returns undefined variable after initially logging it correctly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new to node and have run into a problem I just can't figure out. I'm using node/express and mysql to return the results of a query.

If I console.log the first item in results array, it logs the object correctly.  I then iterate through the results and console.log some data.

After logging everything correctly, the script seems to go back and log that initial array item as "undefined"

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/:make', async (req, res) => {
  pool.query(sql.getAll, [req.params.make], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    // Do something with result.

    console.log(result[0]);

    result.forEach((row) => {
      console.log(row.style);
    });

    res.send('WTF!');
  });
});
```

and here is what I get in terminal:

```
RowDataPacket {
  id: 6103,
  year: '2020',
  make: 'Ram',
  model: '1500 Classic',
  style: 'Truck',
}
Truck
Truck
Truck
undefined
```

Can anyone shed light on what is going on?

When I replace console.log(result[0])  with console.log(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3]), I get the following:

```
RowDataPacket {
  id: 6103,
  year: '2020',
  make: 'Ram',
  model: '1500 Classic',
  style: 'Truck'
} RowDataPacket {
  id: 6103,
  year: '2020',
  make: 'Ram',
  model: '1500 Classic',
  style: 'Truck'
} RowDataPacket {
  id: 6121,
  year: '2020',
  make: 'Ram',
  model: '1500 Classic',
  style: 'Truck'
} undefined
Truck
Truck
Truck
undefined undefined undefined undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a row in the database with style = undefined? That's what it looks like.

Comment: terrymorse - I'm positive none of the styles are undefined.  That undefined is definitely referring to the same object that was console.logged initially, I tested it out many, many times.  I only came to stackoverflow after hours of going down unproductive rabbit holes

Comment: In place of `console.log(result[0]);`, try `console.log(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3]);`. The output may be surprising.

Comment: Here is what I got:

Comment: I added the result to the question.  I'm more confused now

Comment: As you can tell from the output, the fourth row you received from MySQL `result[3]` (if you actually received it) is undefined. No idea why.

Comment: well, it kind of makes me feel better that you're perplexed as well.  Maybe it's an issue with my computer setup or something.  the code and output just doesn't make sense to me.  I wish I knew how to use a debugger with node, I tried but got confused

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the following: 1) the query string you're providing via the `sql.getAll` variable. 2) the results received when you query the DB directly with that query string. 3) the output of `console.log(result.length)`. 4) the options used to initialize your connection for `pool` (will be something like `pool = mysql.createPool({  })`) Happy to review and chime in.